# Unable to receive snmp trap from a siemens device

Tags: snmp

I have a Siemens switch whose IP I have assigned as 192.168.0.1. I have installed the `net-snmp` `snmaptrapd` application on my ubuntu system whose IP is 192.168.0.2 and am trying to get the traps from the Siemens device.

- I see the traps being generated from Siemens device on `wireshark` and ireasoning mibbrowser. But I do not get any traps received in the `snmptrapd` application which should log in `/var/log/syslog`.
- But when I send a `snmptrap` command

  ```shell
  sudo snmptrap -v 1 -c public localhost SN-MSPS-SCX200-MIB::snMspsTrapPowerLine2Up localhost 2 0 '' IF-MIB::ifIndex i 1
  ```

  I get the trap received log in the syslog.

Why doesn't the `snmptrapd` receive traps from the Siemens device? How to receive traps from the Siemens device?

I have added these lines in `snmptrapd.conf` file:

```
authCommunity log,execute,net public
authCommunity log,execute,net private

[snmp] logOption sd

disableAuthorization yes
ignoreAuthFailure yes
```

Comment: Is the trap destination address configured to the Siemens device correct? (Wireshark will typically use promiscuous mode on the network interface, so it can capture even packets that are not specifically sent to the target host. `snmptrapd` cannot do that.) Are the traps sent by the Siemens device actually SNMPv1 or v2 traps, or v2 INFORMs, or are they SNMPv3 traps? If SNMPv1 or v2, is the community name on the traps set to either `public` or `private`, as configured in the receiver?